# Update ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataProperty in ASP.NET MVC application to ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, metadata

I have an old ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.8 project that I'm trying to update to .NET Core 8.0, and I'm running into an issue trying to convert this code:

```
private static ModelMetadata GetPropertyMeta<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> prop)
{
    var dpi = prop.Body is MemberExpression membod
        ? (PropertyInfo)membod.Member
        : GetPropertyMember(prop);

    return ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, dpi.DeclaringType, dpi.Name);
}
```

I also have this in the `global.asax` file:

```
//in Application_Start()
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyMetadataProvider();
```

```
private class MyMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        if (metadata.DisplayName == null && propertyName != null)
        {
            metadata.DisplayName = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(propertyName, @"(\B[A-Z][a-z])", " $1").Trim();

            if (metadata.DisplayName.ToLower().EndsWith(" id"))
               metadata.DisplayName = metadata.DisplayName.Remove((metadata.DisplayName.Length - 3));
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

How can I recreate this functionality in .NET Core? I see that `ModelMetadataProvider` exists, but I'm not sure how to use it in the startup code and then in the function itself.

Any help appreciated!